Selection does not change when a TreeView entry is clicked
I have a TreeView in my Tkinter program where each entry correlates to an Object outside of the tree. Since Tkinter provides no direct way to associate objects with TreeView entries, I must bind functions to events in the tree in order to load the correct data. I use the "<<TreeviewSelect>>" event to detect when an entry has been selected, then load the relevant data for the clicked entry. It works fine when I manually set the selection using selection_set, but the event does not fire when an entry is clicked.
My code is:
    def AddTask(self, task, parent="", select=False):
        tag = str(uuid.uuid1())
        treeItem = self.listTree.insert(parent, END, text = task.name, tags=tag)
        self.listTree.tag_bind(tag, "<<TreeviewSelect>>", self.SelectTask(task))

        if select:
            self.listTree.selection_set(treeItem)
        self.taskToItem[task] = treeItem
        return treeItem
    
    def SelectTask(self, task):
        self.selectedTask = task
        print("select")

This should result in a "select" being printed in the console every time an entry is clicked, but it only happens when an entry is first created using AddTask with select set to True. This indicates that the <<TreeviewSelect>> event does not fire on click.
listTree is created like this:
        self.listTree = ttk.Treeview(self.listFrame, show="tree", selectmode="browse")
        self.listTree.pack(fill=BOTH, side=TOP, expand=True)
        self.listTree.heading("#0", text="Name")


YOU are calling self.SelectTask(task), once only, and passing its return value (which is None) as the function to be called in response to <<TreeviewSelect>> events.  You need to pass a function here, not call it.

I wrapped it in a lambda and it works now
